# UITableView button color issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have some questions to answer with Yes or Not in a `UITableView`, each option (yes/no) is it's own button in the cell.

First, I have to handle the click event, because I have to change button's `backgroundColor` on click and I have to add the clicked row to create another struct with the answers.

My actual code is like this:

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //click row
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return questions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellAnswers", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        
        //iterate here? and how can i do that?
        
        cell.actionYes = {
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .blue
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        }
        
        cell.actionNot = {
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
        
        let question = questions[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.question = question
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Like you see, I have clousures to handle click event and change backgroundColor, but if i click one button, the rest change too.

and my TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonYes: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonNo: UIButton!
    
    var actionYes: (() -> Void)? = nil
    var actionNo: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    @IBAction func answerYes(_ sender: Any) {
        actionYes?()
    }
    
    @IBAction func answerNo(_ sender: Any) {
        actionNo?()
    }
    
    var question: QuestionResponse!{
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    func updateUI(){
        
        question.text = question.value
        
    }
    
}
```

I don't have any idea how to iterate the the cells to fill the correct color on buttons.

Comment: get the cell `indexPath` from the selected cell inside `didSelectRowAt` method and then get the corresponding cell using the tableView method [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)

Comment: The issue is that when you tap yes or no button and you scroll you see also other questions with the same answer?

Comment: @gcharita yup.. for example i answer yes the 1st question, and when i scroll, other questions are marked like yes when i didnt choose any answer yet.. I was reading that i have to iterate in the cell but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing is the result of cell reusing that `UTableView` does.

Whenever a cell is out of the screen, (after scrolling) gets added to a queue to be reused. That's why you need to call [dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell) function to get a cell that you need to prepare for displaying your data. That means that a `UITableViewCell` instance may already have some changes left over from the last time that has been used.

The correct way to deal with a `UTableView` is to keep whatever you change in you datasource. For example you can add an `answer` property to your `QuestionResponse` model, like this:

```
enum Answer {
    case yes, no
}

struct QuestionResponse {
    var answer: Answer?
}
```

And store there the user's answer. Also you have to make sure that you always set the background color of your buttons to avoid unwanted leftover colors from previous usage of the same cell instance:

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return questions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellAnswers", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        
        //iterate here? and how can i do that?
        
        cell.actionYes = {
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .blue
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        }
        
        cell.actionNot = {
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
        
        let question = questions[indexPath.row]
        
        switch question.answer {
        case .yes:
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .blue
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        case .no:
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .blue
        default:
            cell.buttonYes.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            cell.buttonNo.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        }
        
        cell.question = question
        
        return cell
    }
}
```